# Dell P2417H monitor display issues

Tags: display-settings

I ran the self-test on Dell P2419H, can someone confirm if this is acceptable on the text displayed?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbIm9.jpg

Looks very pixelated but Dell support said it's normal.

Comment: Are you running windows 10? 
Maybe you should look up the ClearType adjustment to check out how your text is displayed

Comment: THis is directly on the monitor self-test mode though, not even connecting to a device

Comment: It's called "dell Monitor Built-In Self Test"

Answer (score 0):

I took this from the Manual of your specific monitor

> Poor Focus
>
> Picture is fuzzy,
>   blurry, or
>   ghosting
>
> • Perform Auto Adjust via OSD.
>
> • Adjust the Phase and Pixel Clock controls via OSD.
>
> • Eliminate video extension cables.
>
> • Reset the monitor to factory settings.
>
> • Change the video resolution to the correct aspect ratio

Although maybe this could solve your issue

If Dell support says its normal, then you should try your hook your monitor to your system to check out if its a problem with your video driver o maybe your Operating System as i mentioned earlier

[Dell P2417H  Monitor
User’s Guide - Source Page 56](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1034749984.pdf)

Comment: Thanks heaps but unfortunately with HDMI connected, the AUto Adjust, Phase and Pixel Clock controls via OSD are disabled. :(